# How to make work mobilefirst Mobile browser simulator applet on chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, applet, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I just noticed that because of Java Applet policies on Chrome (https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml... and almost the same for Firefox), mobilefirst Mobile browser simulator not working very well on all applet dependant feature (pictures, ...)

Now I figured out how to make the browser agree applet but even forcing unsecure settings (chrome://plugins/) not solving this problem (a disclaimer always appears when load the page before java execution, makes the page behave without applet)

The last disclaimer is a self signed message and can't get rid of this...

Is there a magic settings makes me find back that tool ? Better, is there a non Applet version of that tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked with a JRE 7.x on Firefox (Warning : Firefox stop NPAPI support end 2016)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome no longer supports the Java Applet in the Mobile Browser Simulator. Please see https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033 . Therefore the Capture, Camera, and File simulation panels will now be blocked in Chrome. Everything else will still function for Chrome in the Mobile Browser Simulator.  The latest Firefox still functions with the applet, so you can use Firefox for the Camera, File and Capture simulations. Be sure to use the simulator in Firefox and then accept the applet permissions (*a refresh of the page may be needed after accepting all the permissions*). Youtube video on accepting the applet permissions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJ_rXdqLmVQ

Comment: That also not working with Firefox because of new Java security policies (http://java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) self signed JAR not accepted anymore (medium level disapeared)

Comment: What version of the MobileFirst Platform are you using? The applet works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Depending wich JVM you use, with JRE 8, self signed applet always need confirmation (then break the test env), there's no medium level security policy anymore. Maybe, I guess, with JRE 7, that can work with firefox, but cannot test it on my platform.